how to set api_key using os library
i try to create model in vscode  . i use langchain, google gemini api , os .
i try this code ->
os.environ("GOOGLE_API_KEY") = 'here is variable of my api key of gemini '

it give this error->
os.environ("GOOGLE_API_KEY") = 'API_KEY'
  ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is this for python?

This question is similar to: How to set environment variables in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Firstly this is not the right way to set environment variable in Python. You need to use a dictionary syntax.
os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"]="youkey"

Also if you are using Google Vertex AI, Google provides an internal authentication mechanism that does not require a key. You can explore :
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth
